# Fail to load radvd.service - Router advertisement daemon for IPv6

Tags: openstack-neutron

I'm facing this issue while setting up the neutron, it leading the OpenStack router not working. Below is output from journalctl -xe.

> Subject: A start job for unit radvd.service has begun execution
> Defined-By: systemd Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
>
> A start job for unit radvd.service has begun execution.
>
> The job identifier is 5471. Jan 28 13:28:10 controller radvd[30829]:
> can't open /etc/radvd.conf: No such file or directory Jan 28 13:28:10
> controller radvd[30829]: Insecure file permissions, but continuing
> anyway Jan 28 13:28:10 controller radvd[30829]: exiting, failed to
> read config file Jan 28 13:28:10 controller systemd[1]: radvd.service:
> Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE Subject: Unit
> process exited Defined-By: systemd Support:
> http://www.ubuntu.com/support
>
> An ExecStartPre= process belonging to unit radvd.service has exited.
>
> The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1. Jan 28
> 13:28:10 controller systemd[1]: radvd.service: Failed with result
> 'exit-code'. Subject: Unit failed Defined-By: systemd Support:
> http://www.ubuntu.com/support
>
> The unit radvd.service has entered the 'failed' state with result
> 'exit-code'. Jan 28 13:28:10 controller systemd[1]: Failed to start
> Router advertisement daemon for IPv6. Subject: A start job for unit
> radvd.service has failed Defined-By: systemd Support:
> http://www.ubuntu.com/support
>
> A start job for unit radvd.service has finished with a failure.
>
> The job identifier is 5471 and the job result is failed. Jan 28
> 13:28:12 controller multipathd[655]: sda: add missing path Jan 28
> 13:28:12 controller multipathd[655]: sda: failed to get udev uid:
> Invalid argument Jan 28 13:28:12 controller multipathd[655]: sda:
> failed to get sysfs uid: Invalid argument Jan 28 13:28:12 controller
> multipathd[655]: sda: failed to get sgio uid: No such file or
> directory

Comment: This seems to be the key problem: `can't open /etc/radvd.conf: No such file or directory`.

Comment: For temporary, I ignored this since I'm not actually using IPv6.

Comment: In this case, don't worry.